# Add variable of superclass to dictionary subclass and read value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, subclass

I'm having trouble accessing a superclass variable from a dictionary in the subclass.
The following code is a simplified example:

```
class SetStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature = 0.0

    def set_temp(self, temp):
        self.temperature = temp


class DoStuff(SetStuff):
    def __init__(self):   
        super().__init__()
        self.info_dict = {"temp": {"current_temp": self.temperature}}

    def print_stuff(self):
        print("temp_var:", self.temperature)
        print("dict:", self.info_dict)



test_stuff = DoStuff()
test_stuff.set_temp(12.1)
test_stuff.print_stuff()
```

The result of the final call is:

```
temp_var: 12.1
dict: {'temp': {'current_temp': 0.0}}
```

Whereas I expected the printed dictionary to contain 12.1. I can't seem to fathom what happens here and how I can fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where `self.info_dict` is set. It's in the `__init__` so the value of self.temperature is indeed zero for `current_temp` because it's being set to the *initial* value of `self.temperature`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. Is there any way to update said variable to its current value?

Comment: You could do `self.info_dict['temp']['current_temp'] = self.temperature`, but you can just call the attribute if you need the value. Unclear why a `dict` would be useful here. If you just need to call the value, dict is a bit redundant for this. You can even index `self.__dict__['temperature']` instead of calling `self.temperature` if you really wanted to.